# Convert an unlabeled NxN matrix to a table of position and values in R

Tags: r

I have an unlabeled N x N matrix like the one below. It is saved in a csv.

```
0.5 0.4 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.4 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.7 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.9 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

**I want to convert this into a data table with `x` coordinates, `y` coordinates, and `values` as the columns** as I believe this is what needs to be done to plot the matrix as a heatmap.

I am completely unfamiliar with R, besides basic syntax, so please be verbose in any suggestions!

Thank you all so much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may read the data with `read.table/read.csv`, convert the data.frame object to matrix (`as.matrix`) and then add the `table` attribute (`as.table`) and convert to data.frame which will return a data.frame with three columns i.e. row, column and the value in the long format

```
as.data.frame(as.table(m1))
```

#### data

```
m1 <- as.matrix(read.table('file.txt', header = FALSE))
```

Comment: Perfect! I had tried this solution previously, but my issue is that I was actually reading in my matrix as a data.table object rather than with as.matrix.

Comment: @Paul `read.table/read.csv` returns a data.frame

Comment: I understand. My issue is that I was (incorrectly) wrapping it like `data.table(read.table(...))` instead of `as.matrix(read.table(...))` based on a previous attempt on a solution. Again, thank you for the help!